# Chart not rendering

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple pie chart which I am trying to make responsive.
My efforts have got me to the point where the chart does not display.
No errors, just a blank screen.

Any ideas why it is not rendering would be gratefully appreciated.

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/SFX4mpaL1fwXraXDR71X?p=preview

```
var pieG = chartLayer.selectAll("g")
        .data([data])
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+[fullWidth/2, fullHeight/2]+")")
```

Comment: text that's longer than the path is not displayed and your paths are just a move command so are 0 length.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not quite understand "your paths are just a move command". Does a path need to be created first?

Comment: check them yourself with a DOM inspector you'll see <path d="M0,0Z" /> which is a zero length path. Z returns to the start but you've not gone anywhere.

Comment: OK, so how do I create the path?

Comment: I've no idea what path you want to create.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the arc generator:

```
var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(chartHeight/2)
    .innerRadius(chartHeight/4)
    .padAngle(0.03)
    .cornerRadius(8);
```

Without defining the `chartHeight`:

```
console.log(chartHeight)//returns undefined
```

So, I just put some magic numbers:

```
var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(150)
    .innerRadius(100)
    .padAngle(0.03)
    .cornerRadius(8);
```

Here is your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/nm4TBcOGN14C9rwDMgRs?p=preview